# How to find all numbers that there distance from given point are less or equall to integer n?

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, search-algorithms, nearest-neighbour

Given a set of numbers $D$ and some number $k$ I want to find all numbers that are in $D$ such that the distance between $k$ and any found number is less or equal to integer $n$?

Example: suppose we have $D=\{5,9,0,6,7\}$ and $k=8$ and $n=1$ then the result should be $\{9,7\}$.

I was thinking to use a k-d tree or VP tree but both as I understand find nearest neighbors and do not care about $n$ in my example, but please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54521918/781723.  lease [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it was cross-posted on SO.

Comment: @D.W.how to delete it ? I am trying to figure out how but in veins

Comment: There is no need now, as I've closed it for you, but in the future: if you log into the account you used to post the question, you will find a link marked "delete" immediately under your question.

Comment: @D.W. thank you. actually I thought that stackoverflow and cs stackovelow have diffrent members so I tried to ask the question fo all members.

Comment: They do have different members, but as explained at the link I gave above, posting the same question on both sites is not allowed.  See that link for an explanation of why.